# Trying to perfect the query

Tags: mysql

I am just looking for rectangular forms as of the moment so I am trying to get it working with vanilla mysql on phpmyadmin, I want to have a database where there are multiple areas that could potentially overlap each other, every area has a "cost" per square pixel, so you can get the cost at a certain point or measure the cost of an entire area while ignoring the parts that are being overlapped, you could also get the average of the total cost existing in the database.

I am wondering if one of you mysql vets could help me write such a query/database schema, I already have something more or less

```
select sum(c.cost) 
from (select x.num as x, y.num as y, max(priority) as maxpriority 
      from numbers x 
      cross join numbers y 
      join costs c 
      on x.num between c.x and c.x + c.deltax 
      and y.num between c.y + c.deltay 
      where x.value between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX and 
      y.value between PIXELY and PIXELY and DELTAY 
      group by x.num, y.num) xyp
join costs c 
on xyp.x between c.x and c.x + c.deltax
and xyp.y between c.y + c.deltay
and xyp.maxpriority = c.priority
```

which seems to be invalid and riddled with bugs, also no database schema was mentioned. I have put multiple days into trying to correct it and make it work but it keeps returning null.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate it.

Here are the schemas:
This is numbers:

```
Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
     1  num int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
```

This is costs:

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  x   int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 2  y   int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 3  deltax  int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 4  deltay  int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 5  priority    int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
```

Comment: You say "I *want* to have a database", and then "no database schema was mentioned".  Do you have a database you are working on, or where do you get that query from?

Comment: Check the where clause in the inner query.`x.value between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX` should probably be `x.value between PIXELX and PIXELX + DELTAX`. Similar for `PIXELY`

Comment: You can't  "test a query", much less "perfect it" without tables to run that query against, so you can't tell if it's "invalid and riddled with bugs". What exactly are we supposed to help you with here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by correcting the errors in the query:

```
select sum(c.cost) 
from (select x.num as x, y.num as y, max(priority) as maxpriority 
      from numbers x 
      cross join numbers y 
      join costs c 
      on x.num between c.x and c.x + c.deltax 
      and y.num between c.y + c.deltay 
      where (x.value between PIXELX and PIXELX + DELTAX)   -- + instead of and
      and (y.value between PIXELY and PIXELY + DELTAY)     -- + instead of and
      group by x.num, y.num) xyp
join costs c 
on (xyp.x between c.x and c.x + c.deltax)
and (xyp.y between c.y and c.y + c.deltay)                 -- added c.y
and xyp.maxpriority = c.priority
```

Then, if you still do not get the desired result, try the inner query alone to see what is returned from that.